# Max VUs at Jmeter distributed testing

Tags: jmeter

Hellow
Which is the maximun number of virtual users that can be testet at a Jmeter distributed test? Is it possible to reach one million of virtual users?
Thak you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on may factors, technically the limit on JMeter end is very high (I think it should be **2<sup>31</sup> − 1** or **2 147 483 647** virtual users)

1. Nature of your application: use cases, is it more about consuming ore creating content, average request and response size, response time, etc.
2. Nature of your test: again, request and response size, need to use pre/post processors and assertions
3. Hardware specifications of your load generators
4. Number of load generators

So I would recommend the following approach:

- Start with a single JMeter instance
- Make sure you have [optimal JMeter configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) and amended your test according to [JMeter best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- Make sure you have monitoring of baseline OS health metrics on that machine
- Start with 1 virtual users and gradually increase the number of running users until you start running out of hardware resources (CPU or RAM or Network or Disk IO will be close to maximum)
- Mind the number of active users at this stage (you can use i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener) - this is how many users you can simulate for particularly that test scenario. Note, the number might be different for other application or other test scenario.
- Multiply the number you get by the number of the load generators you have - if there is > 1M - you are good to go.

---

If you won't be able to simulate that many users there is a workaround, but personally I don't really like it. The idea is that real users don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between actions. Normally you should be simulating these "think times"using [JMeter Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers). But if you lack load generators you can consider the following:

Given 1 virtual user needs 15 seconds to think between operations and response time of your application is 5 seconds, it means that each user will be able to execute only 3 requests per minute. So 1M of users will execute 3M requests per minute which gives us 50 000 requests per second which is also high, but more likely to be achievable.